# ms-access: selecting from table that doesn't exist

Tags: sql, mysql, ms-access

access is connecting to a mysql database. the rowsource of one of a listbox is:

```
SELECT...FROM something INNER JOIN...
```

i cannot find this 'something' anywhere. does it have to be a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be another query (view).

Comment: how do i see all the views that exist?

Answer (score 1):

It would either be a table or a query (verbage for view).

Depending on your version of access look for a button or tab that has the word "Queries" in the same area that has "Tables"

Comment: Technically speaking "query" in Access applies to these terms in other databases: views (for SELECT queries) and stored procedures (for what Access calls "action" queries, i.e., DML statements, e.g., INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). Of course, "stored procedure" in other databases means a lot more than plain old DML statements, as stored procs can have procedural code in those database, whereas there is no such possibility in Jet/ACE SQL (the native flavor for Access).

Comment: @David W. Fenton: Technically speaking, an Access database engine PROCEDURE can contain SQL DDL (e.g. CREATE TABLE), DCL (e.g. CREATE USER) and TCL (e.g. BEGIN TRANSACTION) in addition to SQL DML. Also note that SELECT is a SQL DML statement and if one uses parameters then it will be considered a PROCEDURE rather than a VIEW.